# How get bootstrap in my html read through python socket

Tags: python, html, sockets, http

1. I have been try simple python socket, I have bootstrap.min.css in the same directory of registro.html, but it's not charge style from bootstrap, registro.html, bootstrap.min.css and soket_test.py are in same directory.
2. I have been do request from any browser.

socket_test.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import socket
    import json
    import re


    def getValorArreglo(parametros, clave):
          for indice in parametros:
                if indice.split('=')[0] == clave:
                      return  indice.split('=')[1]
          return None


    '''def setSiguienteVista(action,parametros):
          if action != None and action == '/formulario':'''



    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8791
    server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)    # Create a socket object
    server_sock.bind((host , port))                    # Bind to the port
    server_sock.listen(5)             # Now wait for client connection.
    print ('Entering infinite loop; hit CTRL-C to exit')
    while True:
        # Establish connection with client.
        client_sock, (client_host, client_port) = server_sock.accept()
        print ('Got connection from', client_host, client_port)
        request = b""
        contador = 0
        while not b"\r\n\r\n" in request:
          request += client_sock.recv(1000) # should receive request from client. (GET ....)        
        client_sock.send(b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n')
        client_sock.send(b'Content-Type: text    /html\n')
        client_sock.send(b'\n') # header and body should be separated by additional newline
        # you can paste your 2 text field html here in the <body>
        HtmlFile = open('registro.html','r')
        registro = HtmlFile.read()
        client_sock.send(registro)
        client_sock.close()
```

registro.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Proyecto Sistemas Distribuidos</title>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="formulario"class="form-group" >
            <div class="form-row etiqueta_principal">
                <label class="text-label-principal">REGISTRO DE BACHILLER ASPIRANTE</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 item-div">
                    <label class="col-md-12 item-label" for="nombre1">Primer Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre1" name="nombre1" placeholder="Ingrese primer nombre"
                        required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 item-div">
                    <label class="col-md-12 item-label" for="nombre2">Segundo Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre2" name="nombre2"
                        placeholder="Ingrese segundo nombre">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 item-div">
                <div class="item-div button-div">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Enviar Solicitud</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Your code always sends "registro.html" regardless which file was requested. If bootstrap isn't sent to the browser on request it can't work.

Comment: How can I send it???

Comment: First line of the request consists (separated by space) of command (usually `GET` or `POST`), path of requested file and HTTP version.

Comment: I had add client_sock.send(b'POST\n') above  client_sock.send(b'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n') and now the browser show source page?, sorry by my ignorance...

Comment: I need support.

Comment: You should not send such a request but process it when the browser sends it and then send the requested file.

Comment: Yes, I understand I need send to browser like a response registro.html file, that I did it, but bootstrap file bootstrap.min.css, don't charge to apply all style of bootstrap....

Comment: The standard library supports in package [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) the creation of a simple HTTP server. Maybe you should use this instead of trying to make a server on your own.